# Setting up async await function order

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have tow functions both are async.
i want to make sure one is executed after another
the following code is within async

```
const user= await User.find({
      _id: req.user.id
    });

const userName= `my user name is ${user.userName}`;
const email= `my email is ${user.email}`;

const {response} = await printUser({userName,email};
```

The problem is the printUser function is executed before im finding the user
so the values of userName and email are undefined.

NOTE: the following code is in express router and the find function is working (returing the user)

Comment: did you check if the `find` function returns a promise? if it returns a promise only then await will wait for the find command to be executed fully and return a user(which you are expecting)

Comment: ` User.find` must return promise do you check that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming all of these lines of code are inside an async function as well.

Your problem is that `find` returns an Array of users and not a single user, change

```
const user= await User.find({
      _id: req.user.id
    });
```

To:

```
const user= await User.findOne({
      _id: req.user.id
    });
```

If the code is not within a function but in the main file, then yea you're going to have to use callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use callbacks. Something like below:

```
User.find({
      _id: req.user.id
    }, function (user) {
    printUser(user.userName, user.email); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are mongoose which doesn't return promise for query functions (Read here - https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html#queries-are-not-promises). You can either use `.then` or use `.exec` which will return a proper promise. something like

```
const user = await (User.find({
      _id: req.user.id
    })).exec();

const userName= `my user name is ${user.userName}`;
const email= `my email is ${user.email}`;

const {response} = await printUser({userName,email};
```